# need perl script to connect to database, but don't want the password in plain text

Tags: perl, scripting

I need perl script to connect to database, but don't want the password in plain text.

any suggestion how to hide the password in plain text would be great.

Comment: I am completed new to perl script, need to know how it can be done.

Comment: Being new to Perl does not mean that your question is specific to Perl or that you are not able to read, understand and follow the existing answers to this problem.

Comment: The password must be written within perl script, but not readable as plain text ?

Comment: Even an encrypted password must be decrypted before using it to access the database. If someone has access to read a non-encrypted password then they can also see the result after the code has decrypted an encrypted password. The best solution is to prevent access to your program code.

Comment: This [perl] question was closed as an exact duplicate of a [PHP] question. Bad form, chaps.